# Extracting unique attributes of xml elements with postgresql

Tags: xml, postgresql

Given this xml data type in a postgresql database:

```
<parent>
  <boy age="12">Joe</child>
  <boy age="13">John</child>
  <boy age="12">Jimmy</child>
  <girl age="13">John</child>
  <girl age="11">Jimmy</child>

</parent>
```

How to extract the unique attributes of all the child elements?

This is what I've done so far:
 `SELECT unnest(xpath('(//boy|girl)/@age', col_name)) from table`;

It returns this:

```
unnest
12
13
12
13
11
```

I'd like to return only 11,12,13. So, my next step is to try DISTINCT. I've scoured the internet and tried a few things but it doesnt seem to work:

**Method 1**
`SELECT DISTINCT unnest(xpath('(//boy|girl)/@age', col_name)) from table;`
I get this error: could not identify an equality operator for type xml

**Method 2 - using subquery**
- I thought this should be the answer. I run a query which returns a table of all the attributes. Then I run a select distinct on that table like this:
`SELECT DISTINCT * from (SELECT unnest(xpath('(//a|b|c)/@z', data)) from test3) as x;`

I still get the same error of could not identify an equality operator for type xml

I've also tried this:
`SELECT DISTINCT x from (SELECT unnest(xpath('(//a|b|c)/@z', data)) from test3) as x;`

I get could not identify a comparison function for type xml.

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast the result of your xpath to text, or text and then to int:

```
SELECT DISTINCT unnest(xpath('(//boy|girl)/@age', col_name))::text::int from table;
```

Comment: Perfect. That works! Whats the reason for me casting the result of xpath to text or text to int for DISTINCT to work? Btw, it requires ::for text as well :-)

Comment: Good catch on the `::` I fixed that in my post.  The result of the xpath function is of type xml and there's no built-in method to convert from xml to int.  However, there is a cast from xml to text and a cast from text to int.